# Error: memory exhausted (limit reached?)

Tags: r

Does any one know how to resolve this error ? I am using R in macbook pro.
I am using a clustering package calld rsgcc

```
thm <- gcc.tsheatmap(b[2:5264,], cpus = 1, cormethod = "GCC", distancemethod = "Raw", clustermethod = "complete")
Dimension information for clustered GE matrix: 5263 9


R(18015,0xac5c3a28) malloc: *** mmap(size=16777216) failed (error code=12)
*** error: can't allocate region
*** set a breakpoint in malloc_error_break to debug
R(18015,0xac5c3a28) malloc: *** mmap(size=16777216) failed (error code=12)
*** error: can't allocate region
*** set a breakpoint in malloc_error_break to debug
R(18015,0xac5c3a28) malloc: *** mmap(size=16777216) failed (error code=12)
*** error: can't allocate region
*** set a breakpoint in malloc_error_break to debug
Error: memory exhausted (limit reached?)
```

My session Info is

```
> sessionInfo()
R version 2.15.2 (2012-10-26)
Platform: i386-apple-darwin9.8.0/i386 (32-bit)

locale:
[1] C/UTF-8/C/C/C/C

attached base packages:
[1] stats     graphics  grDevices utils     datasets  methods   base
```

Comment: `memory exhausted (limit reached?` It sounds like you are simply running out of memory so malloc is failing... what if you try with less rows e.g b[2:1000,]...

Comment: it works if it is [1:1000,]

Comment: @user1883491 what do you have in memory.limit()? , maybe you can increase its size using memory.limit(size = ..)

Comment: Does `memory.limit()` work on a Mac?

Comment: @MatthewLundberg `> memory.limit()
[1] Inf
Warning message:
'memory.limit()' is Windows-specific`

Answer (score 9):

Like @arun commented, you need to start using 64 bit R to be able to use the full potential of the 16 gigabytes o of RAM you have. Right now, R can use about 3 gb...

Comment: i just installed 64 bit version on my mac but still it is saying i have 32 bit.

Comment: @user1883491 when you install R, it usually includes both 32- and 64-bit executables.  look in your R folder and run the 64-bit one.  delete the shortcut to the 32-bit one if it's going to confuse you.

Comment: still not working. Here is the erro Error in oV(x[[j]], wts) : node stack overflow

Comment: Please provide us with a more comprehensive and reproducible example.