# R: Error: vector memory exhausted (limit reached?)

Tags: r, macos

I'm using RStudio on mac OS with this version of R:

```
R version 3.5.0 (2018-04-23) -- "Joy in Playing"
Copyright (C) 2018 The R Foundation for Statistical Computing
Platform: x86_64-apple-darwin15.6.0 (64-bit)
```

I have a small matrix like this:

```
                       [,1]  [,2]  [,3]  [,4]  [,5]  [,6]  [,7]  [,8]  [,9] [,10] [,11] [,12] [,13] [,14] [,15]
banks_ernie_cubs      0.554 0.005 0.005 0.085 0.007 0.099 0.030 0.004 0.374 0.465 0.068 0.054 0.011 0.046 0.053
banks_ernie_rip       0.613 0.004 0.005 0.068 0.008 0.067 0.030 0.003 0.308 0.433 0.035 0.023 0.063 0.012 0.071
baylor_kicker_dead    0.484 0.005 0.001 0.033 0.000 0.050 0.000 0.005 0.422 0.180 0.068 0.021 0.010 0.017 0.000
bobbi_kristina_family 0.569 0.003 0.079 0.122 0.006 0.149 0.095 0.014 0.333 0.271 0.087 0.103 0.034 0.128 0.053
```

When I try to launch a command which use this data I get this error:

> Error: vector memory exhausted (limit reached?)

My Mac has only 4GB of RAM, but data are very small... so I don't understand the cause of the error.

What can I try to solve it?

UPDATE:
I try on a server with 64GB of RAM and I get this error:

> Error: cannot allocate vector of size 450.0 Gb

Comment: What command are you launching?

Comment: the command least.squares.capa.ident(<parameteres>) from the Kappalab package

Comment: Hi, have you tried [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14550203/error-memory-exhausted-limit-reached)?

Comment: Yes I'm already using the 64bit version of R, but still not works

Comment: I got the same problem

Comment: Perhaps this post helps
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51295402/r-on-macos-error-vector-memory-exhausted-limit-reached