# Error: vector memory exhausted (limit reached?)

Tags: r, macos

I previously saved a 2.8G RData file and now I'm trying to load it so I can work on it again, but weirdly, I can't. It's giving the error

> Error: vector memory exhausted (limit reached?)

This is weird since I was working with it fine before. One thing that changed though is I upgraded to the latest version of R 3.5.0. I saw a previous post with the same error like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50579676/r-error-vector-memory-exhausted-limit-reached) but it wasn't resolved. I was hopeful with [this](https://www.r-bloggers.com/memory-limit-management-in-r/) solution which increases the `memory.limit()` but unfortunately, it's only available for Windows.

Can anyone help? I don't really understand what's the problem here since I was able to work with my dataset before the update so it shouldn't be throwing this error.

Did the update somehow decreased the RAM allocated to R? Can we manually increase the `memory.limit()` in Mac to solve this error?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Error: vector memory exhausted (limit reached?) R 3.5.0 macOS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51248293/error-vector-memory-exhausted-limit-reached-r-3-5-0-macos)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This change was necessary to deal with operating system memory over-commit issues on Mac OS. From the NEWS file:

```
  \item The environment variable \env{R_MAX_VSIZE} can now be used
  to specify the maximal vector heap size. On macOS, unless specified
  by this environment variable, the maximal vector heap size is set to
  the maximum of 16GB and the available physical memory. This is to
  avoid having the \command{R} process killed when macOS over-commits
  memory.
```

Set the environment variable `R_MAX_VSIZE` to an appropriate value for your system before starting R and you should be able to read your file.

Comment: Awesome insight! Two questions: how do I set that variable to a certain value? and if maximal vector heap size is set to 16 GB by default, why can't it load my data?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51248293/error-vector-memory-exhausted-limit-reached-r-3-5-0-macos/51956149#51956149

Comment: Doesn't fix the problem for me unfortunately