# Error: vector memory exhausted (limit reached?) R 3.5.0 macOS

Tags: r, macos, memory

I've been working for a while with a number of large files containing gene expression data, and I've recently run into an issue with loading that data into R, after upgrading to R 3.5.0. After using about 8GB of memory (my mac has 16GB of RAM), if I try to read in another file, I get the following error:

```
Error: vector memory exhausted (limit reached?)
```

I found a previous post ([Error: vector memory exhausted (limit reached?)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51086959/error-vector-memory-exhausted-limit-reached)) suggesting I try to set the environmental variable R_MAX_VSIZE to a higher value, so I tried the following:

```
Sys.setenv(R_MAX_VSIZE = 16e9)
```

However, I still got the same error. Am I not setting the environmental Variable correctly? is there something that I'm missing?

Session info:

```
R version 3.5.0 (2018-04-23)
Platform: x86_64-apple-darwin15.6.0 (64-bit)
Running under: macOS High Sierra 10.13.5

Matrix products: default
BLAS: /System/Library/Frameworks/Accelerate.framework/Versions/A/Frameworks/vecLib.framework/Versions/A/libBLAS.dylib
LAPACK: /Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Versions/3.5/Resources/lib/libRlapack.dylib

locale:[1] en_US.UTF-8/en_US.UTF-8/en_US.UTF-8/C/en_US.UTF-8/en_US.UTF-8

attached base packages:
[1] stats     graphics  grDevices utils     datasets  methods   base     

other attached packages: [1] data.table_1.11.4

loaded via a namespace (and not attached):
[1] compiler_3.5.0 tools_3.5.0
```

Comment: I get the "Error: vector memory exhausted (limit reached?)" at super random times in R 3.5.0....I check the memory used up and R has around 2GB on a 16GB mac laptop. It's clearly not out of memory. `Sys.setenv('R_MAX_VSIZE'=32000000000)` sets the variable correctly but the error keeps reappearing irrespective.

Comment: I have the same problem with R 3.5.1. My Mac has 8GB of memory, and 80% was used when the error appeared, so it clearly is not because I'm running out of memory. `Sys.setenv('R_MAX_VSIZE'=32000000000)` does not change the `limit` term when I call `gc()`. I have access to a server that doesn't have a limit on vector memory, so I'll have to use it.

Answer (score 28, accepted):

For those using Rstudio, I've found that setting `Sys.setenv('R_MAX_VSIZE'=32000000000)` only works on the command line, and that setting that parameter while using Rstudio does not prevent this error:

`Error: vector memory exhausted (limit reached?)`

After doing some more reading, I found [this](http://r.789695.n4.nabble.com/R-3-5-0-vector-memory-exhausted-error-on-readBin-td4750237.html) thread, which clarifies the problem with Rstudio, and identifies a solution, shown below:

Step 1: Open terminal,

Step 2:

```
cd ~
touch .Renviron
open .Renviron
```

Step 3: Save the following as the first line of `.Renviron`:

```
R_MAX_VSIZE=100Gb
```

Note: This limit includes both physical and virtual memory; so setting _MAX_VSIZE=16Gb on a machine with 16Gb of physical memory may not prevent this error. You may have to play with this parameter, depending on the specs of your machine

Answer (score 15):

R 3.5 has a new system limit on for memory allocation. From the release notes:

> The environment variable R_MAX_VSIZE can now be used to specify 
>          the maximal vector heap size. On macOS, unless specified by this 
>          environment variable, the maximal vector heap size is set to the 
>          maximum of 16GB and the available physical memory. This is to 
>          avoid having the R process killed when macOS over-commits memory.

You can override this. You risk overallocating and killing the process, but that is probably what was happening if you hit a hard wall with R 3.4.4 or whatever you were using before.

Execute the following in Terminal to create a temporary environmental variable `R_MAX_VSIZE` with value 32GB (change to suit):
`export R_MAX_VSIZE=32000000000`

Or if you don't want to open Terminal and run that every time you want to start an R session, you can append the same line to your bash profile. Open Terminal and find your bash profile `open .bash_profile` and, in a text editor, add the line from above.

You will still have to open Terminal and start R from there. You can run R in the terminal by just executing `R` or you can open the GUI `open -n /Applications/R.app`.

To make this change in an R session use `Sys.setenv('R_MAX_VSIZE'=32000000000)`
and to check the value use `Sys.getenv('R_MAX_VSIZE')`

Comment: Doesn't fix the problem for me. Sad face.

Comment: @GordonMcdonald Maybe we can help with a bit more info. Are you finding that after updating R you are getting the vector memory error using code that executed without a problem prior to the update? If that is the case, this solution may help if you adjust upwards the number you assign to `R_MAX_SIZE`.

Comment: @GordonMcDonald `Sys.setenv('R_MAX_VSIZE'=32000000000)` did not work for me. [Apparently](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52029851/vector-memory-exhausted-using-r-package-dtw#comment91156723_52029851), you cannot set R_MAX_VSIZE [after R is started](http://r.789695.n4.nabble.com/R-3-5-0-vector-memory-exhausted-error-on-readBin-tp4750237p4750244.html). Using the answer provided by @GraemeFrost worked for me.

Answer (score 10):

A solution for those who might be unfamiliar with the command line can be found [here](https://community.rstudio.com/t/how-to-set-a-variable-in-renviron/5029/4):

In short, the solution is to use the `usethis` package.

`usethis::edit_r_environ()` will open the .Renviron which is in your home directory. This .Renviron affects all Rstudio work

`usethis::edit_r_environ("project")` will open an .Renviron local to your project. Changes made to this file only affect work done in that particular Rstudio project.

Once open, the `R_MAX_VSIZE` var can be set.

The linked page also links to [this blog](https://rviews.rstudio.com/2017/04/19/r-for-enterprise-understanding-r-s-startup/) which describes R's startup process in great detail.

Comment: Just a clarification note. In the above code, the argument is literally "project". It is not meant to be replaced with the name of your project.

Comment: This is really straightforward, thanks! Had to experiment a bit with the 'R_MAX_VSIZE' value to work out what was large enough. At 64Gb it runs without errors.