# R on MacOS Error: vector memory exhausted (limit reached?)

Tags: r, macos, bioconductor

I'm trying to run an R script (in particular, I am using the "getLineages" function from the Bioconductor package, [Slingshot](https://www.bioconductor.org/packages/devel/bioc/html/slingshot.html).

I'm wondering why the error "vector memory exhausted (limit reached?)" is showing up when I use this function, as it doesn't seem to be the most memory-intensive function compared to the other functions in this package (with the data I am analyzing).

I do understand that there are other questions like this on Stackoverflow, but they all suggest to switch over to the 64-bit version of R. However, I am already using this version. There seem to be no other answers to this issue so far, I was wondering if anyone might know?

The data is only ~120mb in size, which is far less than my computer's 8GB of RAM.

[image: R 64 bit version]

Comment: It sounds like this might address the problem: http://r.789695.n4.nabble.com/R-3-5-0-vector-memory-exhausted-error-on-readBin-td4750237.html

Comment: Will take a look into that solution!

Comment: I reached this error on 3.5.1 when attempting to use ggplot2's "geom_raster" on approximately 664 lat/lon points. This solution above did not work for me. It does seem like a versioning issue as mentioned in the thread however.

Comment: @Aus_10 Did you ever get that resolved? I'm running into a similar situation with geom_raster() and I realized it's due to the lat/long coordinates not being even. It works fie when I use aes(x = col, y = row), so I'm fairly sure its to do with some absurd geometry going on under the hood

Answer (score 171, accepted):

For those using Rstudio, I've found that setting `Sys.setenv('R_MAX_VSIZE'=32000000000)`, as has been suggested on multiple StackOverflow posts, only works on the command line, and that setting that parameter while using Rstudio does not prevent this error:

`Error: vector memory exhausted (limit reached?)`

After doing some more reading, I found [this](http://r.789695.n4.nabble.com/R-3-5-0-vector-memory-exhausted-error-on-readBin-td4750237.html) thread, which clarifies the problem with Rstudio, and identifies a solution, shown below:

Step 1: Open terminal,

Step 2:

```
cd ~
touch .Renviron
open .Renviron
```

Step 3: Save the following as the first line of `.Renviron`:

```
R_MAX_VSIZE=100Gb
```

Step 4: Close RStudio and reopen

Note: This limit includes both physical and virtual memory; so setting _MAX_VSIZE=16Gb on a machine with 16Gb of physical memory may not prevent this error. You may have to play with this parameter, depending on the specs of your machine

Comment: Only the .Renviron version worked for me and I'm on a terminal cmd line.

Comment: In case this is helpful to anyone encountering the same error (I know this thread is oldish!), you can watch R's memory usage in near realtime from the Activity Monitor. I found this useful in diagnosing the issue.

Comment: Perhaps obvious, but I had to reboot R for this to work

Answer (score 44):

This can be done through R studio as well.

```
library(usethis) 
usethis::edit_r_environ()
```

when the tab opens up in R studio, add this to the 1st line: `R_MAX_VSIZE=100Gb` (or whatever memory you wish to allocate).

Re-start `R` and/or restart computer and run the R command again that gave you the memory error.

Answer (score 19):

I had the same problem, increasing the `"R_MAX_VSIZE"` did not help in my case, instead cleaning the variables no longer needed solved the problem. Hope this helps those who are struggling here.

```
rm(large_df, large_list, large_vector, temp_variables)
```

Answer (score 0):

I had this problem when running `Rcpp::sourceCpp("my_cpp_file.cpp")`, resulting in

```
Error: vector memory exhausted (limit reached?)
```

changing the `Makevars` file solved it for me. Currently it looks like

```
CC=gcc
CXX=g++
CXX11=g++
CXX14=g++
cxx18=g++
cxx1X=g++
LDFLAGS=-L/usr/lib
```