# dummy_cols Error: vector memory exhausted (limit reached?)

Tags: r, out-of-memory, dummy-variable

I am attempting to create dummy variables based on a factor variable with more than 200 factor levels. The data has more than 15 million observations. Using the "fastDummies" package, I am using the "dummy_cols" command to convert the factor variable to dummies, and remove the first.

I have read numerous posts on the issue. Several suggest subsetting the data, which I cannot do. This analysis is for a school assignment that requires that I use all included data.

I am using a 16GB RAM Macbook Pro with the 64-bit version of RStudio. The instructions in the post below dictate how to increase the max RAM available to R. However, the instructions seem to imply that I am already at maximum capacity, or that it may be unsafe for my machine to attempt to raise the memory restriction on R.

[R on MacOS Error: vector memory exhausted (limit reached?)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51295402/r-on-macos-error-vector-memory-exhausted-limit-reached)

I'm not sure how to go about posting 15 million rows of data. The following code shows the unique factor levels for the variable in question:

```
unique(housing$city)
[1] 40   80   160  200  220  240  280  320  440  450  460  520  560  600  640 
 [16] 680  720  760  840  860  870  880  920  960  1000 1040 1080 1120 1121 1122
 [31] 1150 1160 1240 1280 1320 1360 1400 1440 1520 1560 1600 1602 1620 1640 1680
 [46] 1720 1740 1760 1840 1880 1920 1950 1960 2000 2020 2040 2080 2120 2160 2240
 [61] 2290 2310 2320 2360 2400 2560 2580 2640 2670 2680 2700 2760 2840 2900 2920
 [76] 3000 3060 3080 3120 3160 3180 3200 3240 3280 3290 3360 3480 3520 3560 3590
 [91] 3600 3620 3660 3680 3710 3720 3760 3800 3810 3840 3880 3920 3980 4000 4040
 [106] 4120 4280 4320 4360 4400 4420 4480 4520 4600 4680 4720 4800 4880 4890 4900
 [121] 4920 5000 5080 5120 5160 5170 5200 5240 5280 5360 5400 5560 5600 5601 5602
 [136] 5603 5605 5790 5800 5880 5910 5920 5960 6080 6120 6160 6200 6280 6440 6520
 [151] 6560 6600 6640 6680 6690 6720 6740 6760 6780 6800 6840 6880 6920 6960 6980
 [166] 7040 7080 7120 7160 7240 7320 7360 7362 7400 7470 7480 7500 7510 7520 7560
 [181] 7600 7610 7620 7680 7800 7840 7880 7920 8000 8040 8050 8120 8160 8200 8280
 [196] 8320 8400 8480 8520 8560 8600 8640 8680 8730 8760 8780 8800 8840 8880 8920
 [211] 8940 8960 9040 9080 9140 9160 9200 9240 9260 9280 9320
```

I used the following commands to create the dummy variables, based on the fastDummies package:

```
library(fastDummies)
housing <- dummy_cols(housing, select_columns = "city", remove_first_dummy = TRUE)
```

I get the following response:

```
Error: vector memory exhausted (limit reached?)
```

I am, again, trying to create 220 dummies based on the 221 levels (excluding the first to avoid issues of perfect collinearity in analyses).

Any help is most welcome. If I am missing something about the preceding suggestions, my apologies; none of them involved the exact issue I am experiencing (in the context of creating dummies) and I am not very proficient in use of the command line in Mac OS.

Answer (score 3):

An update: I used the method in [R on MacOS Error: vector memory exhausted (limit reached?)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51295402/r-on-macos-error-vector-memory-exhausted-limit-reached) of using Terminal to remove the default memory usage cap allotted to R, and was able to perform the operations I needed to (although they took an extremely long time).

However, I am still concerned that this may be problematic for computing power. Could removing these default limits on memory used by R damage my computer? Activity Monitor says that my rsession is using almost 48 GB of RAM when I only have physical memory on board of 16 GB.

I understand that I may be walking the line between a coding and a software question here, but the two in this case are related.