# "Vector memory exhausted" w/ multiple imputation + multilevel model + robust standard errors

Tags: r, linear-regression, r-mice

I am attempting to run a multilevel model with robust standard errors on multiple imputation output from the MICE package. I can't provide the data, unfortunately, but here is the code I'm running:

```
imputed <- mice(impvars, maxit = 5)
barg_imp <-complete(imputed, action = "long", include = TRUE)
fitimp <- with(barg_imp,rlmer(success_new ~ conflict_imp + positiondistance_coun +
                      positiondistance_ep + positiondistance_com + population_log + salience_rel 
                      + (1|prnrnmc)))
```

Note that I'm using `rlmer` from the robustlmm package. It gives me the error "vector memory exhausted (limit reached?)". I've tried out some of the solutions from other threads on this error message that haven't worked.

I'm able to run this all right when using `lmer`. Any suggestions on another way to do robust standard errors here (`coeftest` doesn't work), how to run this code more efficiently or remedying this error? Thank you!

Comment: You saw this post? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51295402/r-on-macos-error-vector-memory-exhausted-limit-reached Can you consider testing with fewer rows (eg, sampling 1:1000), or with fewer elements in your formula?

Comment: sorry to be off tangent - but what does this code do? `(1|prnrnmc)`

Comment: (1|prnrnmc) is specifying the level for fixed effects in the mixed effects model. I did see that thread and it hasn't solved my problem. I will try running on a subset just to make sure it actually works. Thanks!