# R vector memory exhausted for calculating tensor products

Tags: r

I am calculating the tensor products of 60,000 pairs of 28*28 matrices in RStudio (version 3.5.2), and the console shows me "Error: vector memory exhausted (limit reached?)". I don't think my MacBook Pro would have such low capacity (16GB RAM). I tried the `mclapply` method for parallel computing but still don't work. Can anyone provide me some insights? Thanks a lot!

If necessary, the following are my codes. I cannot run the last line.

```
install.packages("keras")
library(keras)
install_keras()
install_keras(method = "conda")

library(keras)
mnist <- dataset_mnist()
str(mnist)

trainx <- mnist$train$x
trainy <- mnist$train$y
testx <- mnist$test$x
testy <- mnist$test$y

trainxr <- trainx
trainxg <- trainx
trainxb <- trainx
testxr <- testx
testxg <- testx
testxb <- testx

#training data
i <- 1
for(i in i:60000){
  randomr <- sample (0:255, 1)
  randomg <- sample (0:255, 1)
  randomb <- sample (0:255, 1)
  trainxr[i,,] <- (randomr/255)*(trainx[i,,]/255)
  trainxg[i,,] <- (randomg/255)*(trainx[i,,]/255)
  trainxb[i,,] <- (randomb/255)*(trainx[i,,]/255)
  i <- i+1
}

#testing data
j <- 1
for(j in j:10000){
  randomr <- sample (0:255, 1)
  randomg <- sample (0:255, 1)
  randomb <- sample (0:255, 1)
  testxr[j,,] <- (randomr/255)*(testx[j,,]/255)
  testxg[j,,] <- (randomg/255)*(testx[j,,]/255)
  testxb[j,,] <- (randomb/255)*(testx[j,,]/255)
  j <- j+1
}

#for training
k <- 1
for(k in k:60000){
  randomminus <- sample (0:255, 1)
  matrixminus <- matrix((randomminus/255):(randomminus/255), nrow = 28, ncol = 28)
  trainxr[k,,] <- trainxr[k,,] - matrixminus
  trainxr[k,,] <- abs(trainxr[k,,])
  trainxg[k,,] <- trainxg[k,,] - matrixminus
  trainxg[k,,] <- abs(trainxg[k,,])
  trainxb[k,,] <- trainxb[k,,] - matrixminus
  trainxb[k,,] <- abs(trainxb[k,,])
  k <- k+1
}

#for testing
l <- 1
for(l in l:10000){
  randomminus <- sample (0:255, 1)
  matrixminus <- matrix((randomminus/255):(randomminus/255), nrow = 28, ncol = 28)
  trainxr[l,,] <- trainxr[l,,] - matrixminus
  trainxr[l,,] <- abs(trainxr[l,,])
  trainxg[l,,] <- trainxg[l,,] - matrixminus
  trainxg[l,,] <- abs(trainxg[l,,])
  trainxb[l,,] <- trainxb[l,,] - matrixminus
  trainxb[l,,] <- abs(trainxb[l,,])
  l <- l+1
}

#tensor product
stepone <- matrix(1:1, nrow=21952, ncol=28)
steptwo <- matrix(1:1, nrow=28, ncol=28)
trainxtensor_a <- trainxr %x% trainxg
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [R on MacOS Error: vector memory exhausted (limit reached?)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51295402/r-on-macos-error-vector-memory-exhausted-limit-reached) - try adding ``R_MAX_VSIZE=100Gb`` to your ``.Renviron``

Comment: Thanks for your reply, user438383. I have tried this method but this didn't work:(

Comment: The output of the last line if you had infinite resources would be an array 60000^2 by 784 by 784, which is pretty large. Is that actually what you are expecting?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm guessing you intending to collapse the 2nd and 3rd dimensions in that tensor product. Perhaps you want something like this:

```
library(tensor)
trainxtensor_a <- tensor(trainxr, trainxg, c(2,3), c(2,3))
```

Although you should try a smaller dataset to check if it is doing what you expect first:

```
trainxtensor_a <- tensor(trainxr[1:5,,], trainxg[1:5,,], c(2,3), c(2,3))
```

Comment: Thank you very much! Just one little question: is "tensor" a package that I should install, like `install.packages("tensor")` and then `library(tensor)`? It seems like the environment has no reaction when I'm using the package. Thanks again for your great effort!

Comment: Yes, use `install.packages("tensor")` to install it before the libary call which just loads it up. You can also do it from the menu Tools->Install Packages in RStudio. If you use R a lot you'll be installing lots of packages...

Comment: Actually my computer ran that program for over an hour That's really an extensive job. I think the method you provided is correct. Overall, thank you for your help!