# brms add_criterion how to manage large brmsfit models

Tags: r, memory

I would like to get some overview of what the options are for model comparison in brms when the models are large (brmsfit objects of ~ 6 GB due to 2000000 iterations).

My immediate problem is that add_criterion() won't run after models are finished on my laptop (16GB memory). I got the error message "vector memory exhausted (limit reached?)"; after which I increased the memory cap on R in Renviron to 100GB (as described here: [R on MacOS Error: vector memory exhausted (limit reached?)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51295402/r-on-macos-error-vector-memory-exhausted-limit-reached)). The total memory usage goes up to about 90 GB; I get error messages in R when I want to estimate both 'waic' and 'loo', if I just estimate 'loo', R invariably crashes.

What are my options here and what would be the recommendations?

1. Use the cluster - local convention is to use a single node, is this recommendable? (I guess not, as we have 6, 10, and 16GB cores. Any (link to) advice on parallelising R on a cluster is welcome.)
2. Is it possible to have a less dense posterior in brms, i.e. sample less during estimation, as in BayesTraits?
3. Can I parallelise R/RStudio on my own laptop?
4. ...?

Many thanks for your advice!