# Error on Mac using R with Seurat: vector memory exhausted

Tags: r, macos, seurat

I'm working with R using the Seurat package on mac.

The data I downloaded is on [GEO](https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/geo/query/acc.cgi?acc=GSE93374) and the file is - GSE93374_Merged_all_020816_BatchCorrected_LNtransformed_doubletsremoved_Data.txt.gz

I guess the file I've downloaded is too big because after trying to normalize the data using Seurat, I received the following error code:

```
Error: vector memory exhausted (limit reached?)
```

I followed the thread on [Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52612921/11029928) but it didn't help. My machine has 16GB, and I guess that's why, according to the "NOTE" on the answer, it wasn't helpful.

What can I do?
Maybe try and minimize the size of the text file?

Thanks

Comment: You have to show which commands exactly you used for reading-in the count file. Because 16GB is not bad actually ... Can you show us the exact code from reading-in until occurrence of error? - I see when you try to normalize that data - how did you normalize?

Comment: I see that GSE file is less than half GB in size - so Seurat - using sparse matrix - should be able to deal with it.

Comment: This guy had same error on a Mac with 16GB RAM 64 bit - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51295402/r-on-macos-error-vector-memory-exhausted-limit-reached - His solution was: open in home the `~/.Renviron` file - if not existing, create. then write into `R_MAX_VSIZE=100Gb` - instead manually creating the site, one can use the `usethis` package and do `usethis::edit_r_environ()` which opens dialog where you set the variable. Some other guy, in addition deleted all other files containing memory-consuming variables using `rm(someObject1, someObject2, ...)` which freed memory in addition.

Comment: @Gwang-JinKim Thanks' but I've tried this guy's solution and it didn't work. I added to my question the reference to that thread on StackOverflow.

Comment: but your machine is 64bit or 32bit?

Comment: @Gwang-JinKim 64-bit