# R studio keeps crashing

Tags: r

I am trying to run a random forest model on my Macbook Air M2 (base model)

This is the code I was trying to execute.

```
# TEST
library(dplyr) # for data manipulation
library(caret) # for machine learning 

# Select relevant columns for analysis
selected_cols <- c("Year", "Month", "DayofMonth", "DayOfWeek", "DepTime", "CRSDepTime", "ArrTime", "CRSArrTime", "UniqueCarrier", "FlightNum", "Origin", "Dest", "Distance", "Cancelled", "CancellationCode")

flight_data <- Flight_Details_2003 %>% select(selected_cols)

# Create a delay variable by subtracting the scheduled departure time from the actual departure time. We will also filter out cancelled flights and negative delays
flight_data <- flight_data %>% mutate(DepDelay = DepTime - CRSDepTime) %>% 
  filter(Cancelled == 0, DepDelay >= 0)

# create a new fata frame with the delay information by airport and date:
airport_data <- flight_data %>% group_by(Year, Month, DayofMonth, Origin) %>% 
  summarize(TotalDelay = sum(DepDelay))

# Merge the delay data with itself to create a delay-by-airport-by-date matrix:
delay_matrix <- merge(airport_data, airport_data, by = c("Year", "Month", "DayofMonth"))

# Create a new column that indicates if a delay occured in the destination airport due to a delay in the origin airport
delay_matrix <- delay_matrix %>% mutate(CascadingDelay = ifelse(TotalDelay.x > 0 & TotalDelay.y == 0, 1, 0))

# Prepare data for machine learning
# Drop unnecessary columns
delay_matrix <- delay_matrix %>% select(-c("TotalDelay.x", "TotalDelay.y"))

# Convert data to binary format
delay_matrix$CascadingDelay <- factor(delay_matrix$CascadingDelay, levels = c(0,1), labels = c("No", "Yes"))

# Split data into training and testing sets
set.seed(123)
train_index <- createDataPartition(delay_matrix$CascadingDelay, p = 0.7, list = FALSE)
train_data <- delay_matrix[train_index,]
test_data <- delay_matrix[-train_index,]

# Randomly sampling a smaller portion of the training data because of this error: vector memory exhausted (limit reached?)
set.seed(123)
sample_size <- 10000
train_data_sample <- train_data[sample(seq_len(nrow(train_data)), size = sample_size), ]


# train the machine learning model using a random forest algorithm:

# Train the model
model <- train(CascadingDelay ~ ., data = train_data, method = "rf", trControl = trainControl(method = "cv", number = 10))

# Check model accuracy
confusionMatrix(model, test_data$CascadingDelay)
```

I have a very large data I am running it on.
These are the information I can get without exploding this whole screen.

```
> str(flight_data)
'data.frame':   3109403 obs. of  16 variables:
 $ Year            : int  2003 2003 2003 2003 2003 2003 2003 2003 2003 2003 ...
 $ Month           : int  1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 ...
 $ DayofMonth      : int  31 2 5 1 4 5 6 7 13 16 ...
 $ DayOfWeek       : int  5 4 7 3 6 7 1 2 1 4 ...
 $ DepTime         : int  1724 1053 1035 1713 1710 1832 1710 1712 1714 1711 ...
 $ CRSDepTime      : int  1655 1035 1035 1710 1710 1710 1710 1710 1710 1710 ...
 $ ArrTime         : int  1936 1726 1636 1851 1835 1951 1843 1839 1835 1837 ...
 $ CRSArrTime      : int  1913 1634 1634 1847 1847 1847 1847 1847 1847 1847 ...
 $ UniqueCarrier   : chr  "UA" "UA" "UA" "UA" ...
 $ FlightNum       : int  1017 1018 1018 1020 1020 1020 1020 1020 1020 1020 ...
 $ Origin          : chr  "ORD" "OAK" "OAK" "IAD" ...
 $ Dest            : chr  "MSY" "ORD" "ORD" "BOS" ...
 $ Distance        : int  837 1835 1835 413 413 413 413 413 413 413 ...
 $ Cancelled       : int  0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 ...
 $ CancellationCode: chr  NA NA NA NA ...
 $ DepDelay        : int  69 18 0 3 0 122 0 2 4 1 ...
```

After running the codes, I will be asked to restart R.

[image]

It started off as an error: vector memory exhausted (limit reached?)

and I saw some other thread on stackoverflow ([R on MacOS Error: vector memory exhausted (limit reached?)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51295402/r-on-macos-error-vector-memory-exhausted-limit-reached)) stating that I can do something with my terminal to increase the physical and virtual memory. So I did and now it just crashes instead of showing the error.