# vector memory exhausted using R package dtw

Tags: r, dtw

I am trying to use R package `dtw` to calculate the distance between two numeric vectors. Here is a sample of my code:

```
testNumbers <- sample(seq(from = 1, to = 60), size = 60000, replace = TRUE)
testNumbers2 <- sample(seq(from = 1, to = 60), size = 60000, replace = TRUE)

Sys.setenv('R_MAX_VSIZE'=32000000000)
Sys.getenv('R_MAX_VSIZE')
dtw(testNumbers, testNumbers2, distance.only = TRUE)
```

I will be using wav files that have been decoded, but that hasn't worked either, so I've been using this sample data. As per [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14550203/error-memory-exhausted-limit-reached) post, I checked to make sure I am running the 64bit version of R (and I think that I am, because when I start R/R studio I see this: `Platform: x86_64-apple-darwin15.6.0 (64-bit)`. I also changed the memory size (and checked the setting) in the code above as per [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51248293/error-vector-memory-exhausted-limit-reached-r-3-5-0-macos) post, but I still get this error message `Error: vector memory exhausted (limit reached?)`

Comment: Well, do you have enough RAM? Assuming `dtw` returns a `60,000x60,000` distance matrix, in the worst case scenario you need up to ~30 GB of RAM (`sizeof(double) * 60000 * 60000 / 10^9`, assuming `sizeof(double)` = 8 byte). Have you tried establishing that `dtw` works as expected with smaller vectors?

Comment: I didn't realize how much RAM that would take up. Guess I need to find a computer with much more RAM. I tried it on a smaller frame and it does work. thanks!

Comment: @MauritsEvers, do you know if there is a less computationally-intensive way to do dynamic time warping? thanks!

Comment: @Lisa If you're only using the `symmetric1` or `symmetric2` step patterns and no backtracking, my [`dtw_basic`](https://rdrr.io/cran/dtwclust/man/dtw_basic.html) implementation only allocates two columns of the distance matrix at once. See also [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50776685/5793905).

Comment: @Alexis, thanks for your comment! I tried it but I am still getting the error with my relatively short sample data. thanks anyway!

Comment: @Lisa Unfortunately I can't reproduce your problem, with your sample data I get no error in my machine (although it does take around a minute to finish). The other answer you linked to seems to be wrong, you cannot set `R_MAX_SIZE` after starting R, see [this answer](http://r.789695.n4.nabble.com/R-3-5-0-vector-memory-exhausted-error-on-readBin-tp4750237p4750244.html) (and the other posts there too).

Comment: Oh and BTW, if you get that problem fixed, also consider using either [Keogh's](https://rdrr.io/cran/dtwclust/man/lb_keogh.html) or [Lemire's](https://rdrr.io/cran/dtwclust/man/lb_improved.html) lower bound. Depending on how noisy your data is, it might be enough, and considerably faster.